# Changing the refractive index of biological tissue using Radio Frequency (RF)

Tags: electromagnetism, refraction, doppler-effect, radio-frequency

I have been looking into changing the refractive index of a specific medium initially using Ultrasound in a known location via a mechanical Doppler shift of the emitter (Mahan et al., 1998) which has been demonstrated in biological tissue but I have been trying to find if this is also possible using Radio Frequency to change the refractive index of biological tissue? Radio Frequency waves can change the refractive index of certain mediums using electro-optic modulators, and I was wondering if there were certain conditions to a medium which were required for RF waves to alter the Refractive index?